# how to use file naming in pascal case of extensions .tsx, and .jsx in my .eslintrc.js

Tags: eslint

I am using this library: [eslint-plugin-filenames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-filenames)

I'm new with this `eslintrc` stuff, and I want to know how to make my files with .`tsx` or `.jsx` extensions forced to be called in `PascalCase` format.

For example, I get this file in my project: `src/pages/my_component.tsx`.

I need `MyComponent.tsx` insted of `my_component.tsx`

This is the content of my file `.eslintrc.js`

```
/* eslint-env node */
module.exports = {
root: true,
env: {
    node: true,
},
parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'prettier', 'json', 'jest','filenames'], // I include "filenames"
extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    'plugin:jest/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
],
rules: {
    'linebreak-style': ['error', 'unix'],
    quotes: ['error', 'single'],
},
};
```

I have read the documentation and I don't know how to specify my need, something like this:

```
rules: {"filenames/match-exported": [ 2, "pascal" ]} //how to define PascalCase to `.tsx` or `.jsx`
```

How can do it work?

Comment: Did you get any solution to this?